# PHP Getting value from a function by form

Tags: php, arrays, forms, function

I want to get a value by the function with forms as the user input but I don't think I'm doing it right can anybody help me.

The code is like when enter number 1 in the form then it will output it by the days like Sunday.

Output:-

```
Enter days values between (0-6): 1
The day is Monday.
```

My Code:-

```
<?php
        function day_of_week($week){
           $week = $_POST['week'];
           $week = array(0 => Sunday, 1 => Monday, 2 => Tuesday, 3 => Wednesday, 4 => Thursday, 5 => Friday, 6 => Saturday);

            return $week;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $value = $_POST['value'];
            echo "The day is " . day_of_week($value);
        }
    ?>

    <form method="POST" action="">
        <label>Enter days value between (0-6):</label>
        <input type="text" name="value">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

I search some code and some code the week can be assigned like

```
date('w'); 

if(date('w') == 1){
    echo "its monday baby";
}
```

or also in case code. But I'm not too sure how to actually call the value properly and assigning. Which one is better for assigning, array or date() or case for assigning?

Do help me out to explain why my value is not showing properly too.

Appreciate anyone's helps thank you so much.

Comment: Your function day_of_week($week)s wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function as

```
function day_of_week($x){
    $week = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    return $week[$x];
}
```

Don't forget to fill the **action** part in your form.

```
<form method="post" action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>'>
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't actually show the output why is that? I did write echo

Comment: Your form action is empty. **<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">**

Comment: I still can't get the answer to show but what does `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>` do actually?

Comment: It means your form data will be PHP processed in the same file.
Your submit button not properly designed (missing **name** to triggering the POST call*. Replace it with **<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">**

Comment: Oh I learn something new thank you so that mean if i want something to be process in the same file i use `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a double quote to a string in key-value pair and then return the days with its position

```
<?php 
function day_of_week($day){
           $week = array(0 => "Sunday", 1 => "Monday", 2 => "Tuesday", 3 => "Wednesday", 4 => "Thursday", 5 => "Friday", 6 => "Saturday");

            return $week[$day];
        }

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $value = $_POST['value'];
            echo "The day is " . day_of_week($value);
        }
?>
 <form method="POST" action="">
        <label>Enter days value between (0-6):</label>
        <input type="text" name="value">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Oh okay, but what the difference between double quotes and single quote because sometimes I come across a whole code that only uses a single quote and sometimes there like mixes with a single and double quote. Why is that?

Comment: Hi, it doesn't actually show the output why is that? I did write echo.

Answer (score 1):

Generate days of week dynamically by for loop with built-in function `date` with format `l` which represents the day of the week.

```php
$weekdays = [];
for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){
    $weekdays[$i] = date('l', strtotime("Sunday this week +$i days"));
}
```

So array `$weekdays` will contains days starting from index 0 which is *Sunday* through *Saturday*.

```php
print_r($weekdays);
```

**Prints:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sunday
    [1] => Monday
    [2] => Tuesday
    [3] => Wednesday
    [4] => Thursday
    [5] => Friday
    [6] => Saturday
)
```

It would be better to use `type="number"` instead of `text`, And use some attributes such as `start` and `max`.

```html
<input type="number" name="value" start='0' value="2" max="6">
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me some tips and the start and max is like telling it can't be over this number right?

Comment: No problem! Yeah that is what I meant, since it is number, and actually It can be forced to exceed the range of max 6, but you need to control it in the back-end with PHP.

Comment: Oh, okay I see really thank you I will take note of this. :)